# Oracle Update statement hanging

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle Update statement that is hanging when previous similar updates in the same script are finishing in about an hour.

I have two tables:

Table A: ID, Masked_Account, Original_Account (9+ million rows, a cross-reference table).

Table B: UID, Prefix_Pan, Pan, Masked (1.3+ billion rows).

I'm trying to update the Table B Pan column with the Table A Masked_Account column in each instance where the Table B Pan column matches aTable A Original_Account column.

I am doing the Update in batches of 100 million records per batch with a subsequent Commit.

For example, the below listed Update SQL script finishes in about an hour:

```
UPDATE [TABLE B] optim
SET optim.PAN = (SELECT MASKED_ACCOUNT FROM [TABLE A] pans
                 WHERE optim.PAN = pans.ORIG_ACCOUNT), optim.MASKED = '1'
WHERE optim.OPTIM_UID BETWEEN 1200000000 AND 1300000000
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM [TABLE A] pans
            WHERE optim.PAN = pans.ORIG_ACCOUNT);
```

My last Update SQL statement hangs and never finishes:

```
UPDATE [TABLE B] optim
SET optim.PAN = (SELECT MASKED_ACCOUNT FROM [TABLE A] pans
                 WHERE optim.PAN = pans.ORIG_ACCOUNT), optim.MASKED = '1'
WHERE optim.OPTIM_UID > 1300000000
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM [TABLE A] pans
            WHERE optim.PAN = pans.ORIG_ACCOUNT);
```

Explain Plan (dbms_xplan.display) results:

```
Plan hash value: 4037184420

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT                      |                              |   250 |  9250 |   465K  (1)| 00:00:10 |
|   1 |  UPDATE                               | OPTIM_SMRY_FTR_CHKMC_EXTRACT |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI                |                              |   250 |  9250 |   239K  (1)| 00:00:05 |
|   3 |    INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN       | IDX_PANS_ORIG_ACCT           |    82 |   902 | 10123   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| OPTIM_SMRY_FTR_CHKMC_EXTRACT |    32M|   796M|   228K  (1)| 00:00:05 |
|*  5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | PK_OP_47                     |    22M|       | 53465   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | PANS                         |     1 |    22 |   604   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | IDX_PANS_ORIG_ACCT           |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("OPTIM"."PAN"="PANS"."ORIG_ACCOUNT")
   5 - access("OPTIM"."OPTIM_UID">1300000000)
   7 - access("PANS"."ORIG_ACCOUNT"=:B1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=AUTO)
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do differently on the last Update SQL (optim.OPTIM_UID > 1300000000) so that it won't hang or how I should approach the entire Update process differently?

Comment: a lot of questions.  are there really 100 mm rows between 1200000000 and 1300000000?  My guess is no.  You probably have way more rows that are > 1300000000.  Have you checked for blocking locks?  Does it seem to be moving along? (using undo/rollback) what do your dbas say?

Comment: There really is 100 million rows between 1200000000 and 1300000000.  Optim_UID is really 'rownum'.  Total rowcount for Table B is 1,322,566,115.  The last time I tried to run the last Update batch ( > 1300000000) I didn't see any blocking locks but had been running for 22+ hours.  Currently can't get the dbas to look at it due to other higher priorities.

Comment: 1.3 Billion updates and each one of them requires a sub-query for masked_account.  And I believe the EXISTS portion of this will also fire for each row.  It might be faster to JOIN the two tables and insert into a work table?  Then drop and rename? Is there an index on optim.PAN that could be disabled first?

Comment: Can you please run explain plan in the update and edit the question with results.

Comment: If you look at EVENT in V$SESSION while the slow or hung query is running you can see if it is waiting on a lock. A lock would be a type of enqueue wait event. You can also see this in various GUI tools.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - Is there a particular Select statement on the PLAN_TABLE you would like me to run or is Select * ok?

Comment: This is just a horrible way to do this. A much better approach is to create a new table with the rows you want, rather than delete the rows you don't.

Answer (score 1):

**Rely on the `OPTIM.MASKED` Column in Lieu of Using a Correlated Subquery in Predicate**

It sounds like the `optim.masked` column is set to `1` only after it is masked. It would be ideal to know its default behavior.

-Can it be set to `NULL`?

-Perhaps it is set to `0` by default?

-What constraints are on this column?

Assuming it can be set to `NULL` and it is only set to `1` after it has been masked, could you not do this (remove the correlated subquery in predicate):

```
 UPDATE [TABLE b] optim
SET optim.pan = (SELECT masked_account FROM [TABLE A] pans
                 WHERE optim.pan = pans.orig_account), 
    optim.masked = '1'
WHERE optim.masked != '1'
OR optim.masked IS NULL;
```

This approach assumes that the correlated sub-query in the predicate is the source of the performance and locking issues.

---

You should check to see if your statement is resulting in a lock is to query the v$locked_object view and look for locks associated with your session.

---

If we can not rely on `optim.masked` to update the `optim` table, I would look at using a Merge statement to avoid the correlated subquerying. Table A has one record for a given `orig_account` (which is necessary for merge's deterministic functionality).  You can check to see what the primary key is for table A.  I assume that `orig_account` is the primary key.

```
MERGE INTO [TABLE b] optim USING [TABLE A] pans ON ( optim.pan = pans.orig_account )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET optim.pan = pans.masked_account,
optim.masked = '1';
```